# How to refresh data-ng-init using directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to refresh the variable assigned in data-ng-init whenever source data changes.

I know how to do that from controller. But is there anyway to do it from html using some directive.

Below is sample demo i have done, were you will see Car and Bike Section
When you click "Add Car" listing and counts get changed as i'm using from the direct source

When you click "Add Bike", 
bikeData is not get refreshed, as it holds initial json value only.

`data-ng-init="bikeData = (sorted | filter: { type: 'bike' }:true)"`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/9jxQK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the bikeData isn't refreshed after. You either need to watch for changes on the your `sorted` object and update bikeData. Or you can simply slap the same expression you have in your `data-ng-init` to your `ng-click` directive. See demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/9jxQK/1/

Another option would be to get rid of the data-ng-init and bind your ng-repeat to the `sorted` object like you do with cars. For example:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in sorted | filter: { type: 'bike' }:true">
```